# Where I can add WHERE statement in this query of MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this query statement:

*I cut some code from query to make this post so ignore `NATURAL JOIN %1$sremote_servers` lines

```
$template = 'SELECT %1$sserver_homes.*,  
        FROM %1$sserver_homes
        NATURAL JOIN %1$sremote_servers
        NATURAL JOIN %1$sconfig_homes
        LEFT JOIN %1$sgame_mods 
            NATURAL JOIN %1$sconfig_mods
            ON %1$sserver_homes.home_id=%1$sgame_mods.home_id
        LEFT JOIN %1$shome_ip_ports 
            NATURAL JOIN %1$sremote_server_ips 
            ON %1$sserver_homes.home_id=%1$shome_ip_ports.home_id
        WHERE `force_mod_id` IN
        (
            SELECT `force_mod_id`
            FROM `%1$shome_ip_ports`
            WHERE `force_mod_id` = %1$sgame_mods.mod_id OR %1$shome_ip_ports.force_mod_id = 0
        )
        OR %1$shome_ip_ports.force_mod_id IS NULL LIMIT '.$gethome_page_forlimit.','.$home_limit.';';
```

I need to select all gameserver where **home_cfg_id**

so I need to add WHERE Statement on above query

```
WHERE `home_cfg_id` IN
(
SELECT `home_cfg_id`
FROM `%1$sserver_homes`
WHERE `home_cfg_id` = '.$home_cfg_id.'
)
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be in your last WHERE clause. Remember to place () around the OR statements. So, your WHERE clause should look something like this:

```
WHERE [table].home_cfg_id = [your condition] 
    AND (force_mod_id IN ([your select statment]) 
        OR %1$shome_ip_ports.force_mod_id IS NULL)
```

Hope this gets you on the right path.

----- UPDATE ----
Something like this (make sure to change [] to your needing code):

```
$template = 'SELECT %1$sserver_homes.*,  
                   FROM %1$sserver_homes
                    NATURAL JOIN %1$sremote_servers
                    NATURAL JOIN %1$sconfig_homes
                    LEFT JOIN %1$sgame_mods 
                        NATURAL JOIN %1$sconfig_mods
                        ON %1$sserver_homes.home_id=%1$sgame_mods.home_id
                    LEFT JOIN %1$shome_ip_ports 
                        NATURAL JOIN %1$sremote_server_ips 
                        ON %1$sserver_homes.home_id=%1$shome_ip_ports.home_id
                    WHERE `force_mod_id` IN
                    (
                        SELECT `force_mod_id`
                        FROM `%1$shome_ip_ports`
                        WHERE [table].home_cfg_id [your operation, = or like] [your condition] AND (`force_mod_id` = %1$sgame_mods.mod_id OR %1$shome_ip_ports.force_mod_id = 0
                    )
                    OR %1$shome_ip_ports.force_mod_id IS NULL) LIMIT '.$gethome_page_forlimit.','.$home_limit.';
```

Comment: you mean i add you'r WHERE statement before last line ?